# Are there any javascript documentation tools in Netbeans?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

Netbeans has the ability to create an HTML5/JavaScript project.

I have written a bunch of javascript code that I would like to document. The javascript functions/classes are documented in the source code using java-style comment blocks and "standard" tags (e.g. @param).

I am looking for some way to generate an html or json document from the javascript files. For example, in Netbeans you can generate a JavaDoc via Ant. Is there something similar for a HTML5/JavaScript project?

BTW, I don't use Node.js and I don't want to install npm/node just to generate docs...